# Mendeley Web Importer with single page application

Tags: mendeley

We've recently added COinS metadata to our website to support better integration with reference managers. An example of a page with the metadata in it is here: https://www.lens.org/lens/scholar/search/results. This part of our site is written like a single page application, so the Mendeley Web Importer doesn't detect the COinS elements. It does pick up the DOIs, but any results without DOIs aren't detected by the Mendeley Web Importer. We're dispatching events to the Zotero Connector so that it works well on these pages, but I can't find any equivalent function for the Mendeley Web Importer. Is there any way to trigger the Mendeley Web Importer to check the page again for COinS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For books only (i.e. `rft_val_fmt=info:ofi/fmt:kev:mtx:book`), could you try setting the title on the `rft.btitle` parameter instead of `rft.title` please?

The Mendeley Web Importer only supports the following formats at the moment:

- info:ofi/fmt:kev:mtx:book
- info:ofi/fmt:kev:mtx:journal

I can see at least one format in your page that will be ignored by the Mendeley Web Importer:

- info:ofi/fmt:kev:mtx:dc

Comment: Thanks, using `btitle` for books helped. And now that I know the Mendeley Web Importer only looks at books and journals, it seems to work a lot better. One other thing I noticed - it still doesn't pick up page transitions. For example, if I click one of the article links, and then click the Mendeley Web Importer button, I see results in the Mendeley Wbe Importer for that article only. If I click Back and go back to the search results and then click the Mendeley Web Importer button again, the results don't change. Is there any way to trigger a "refresh" of that list?

Comment: Once the Mendeley Web Importer has been "dropped" onto a page, it does not reprocess it even if additional references are added later on. The only option is to manually (or programmatically) refresh the page which does not play well with SPAs. It _may_ be possible to trick the Mendeley Web Importer into reprocessing the page by programmatically deleting its <iframe> element but I wouldn't necessarily recommend doing so.

Comment: Thanks, removing the `iframe` or it's parent `div` broke the Web Importer totally. We'll just add some instructions to our help documentation.